# How to fix DeviceTokenNotForTopic for iOS push notification?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I am getting `DeviceTokenNotForTopic` when trying to test push notification in sandbox environment.

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -v -d '{
"aps": {
  "alert": {
      "title": "Hello Mate",
      "body": "Thanks"
   },
  "sound": "default",
  "badge": 2
},
"aditional-info": "Test"
}' -H "apns-topic: ca.xlogix.test.ios.push.example" -H "apns-priority: 10" --http2 --cert aps-dev.pem https://api.sandbox.push.apple.com/3/device/7b97568a823edevicetokenhere7c4f5
```

I am following the example from https://gokulgovind26.medium.com/make-your-own-apns-pusher-40aeabe5034e

I have downloaded the Apple Sandbox Push Services certificate, imported to keychain, exported to p12 and converted to pem.

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate credentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {
    print(credentials.token)
    let deviceToken = credentials.token.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
    print("pushRegistry -> deviceToken :\(deviceToken)")
}
```

How to fix this?

---

I also tried Pusher, but it is not connecting to the APNS server. Also using latest certificate, import fails saying no certificate found.

---

```
./push.sh
*   Trying 17.188.168.149:443...
* Connected to api.sandbox.push.apple.com (17.188.168.149) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / AEAD-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=api.development.push.apple.com; OU=management:idms.group.533599; O=Apple Inc.; ST=California; C=US
*  start date: Dec 10 00:29:46 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Jan  9 00:29:45 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.sandbox.push.apple.com" matched cert's "api.sandbox.push.apple.com"
*  issuer: CN=Apple Public Server RSA CA 12 - G1; O=Apple Inc.; ST=California; C=US
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x7fbc8e80ca00)
> POST /3/device/7b97568a823edevicetokenherea4b072929b7e7c4f5 HTTP/2
> Host: api.sandbox.push.apple.com
> user-agent: curl/7.79.1
> accept: */*
> apns-topic: ca.xlogix.test.ios.push.example
> apns-priority: 10
> content-length: 146
> content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 1000)!
< HTTP/2 400 
< apns-id: BF2F2FE8-AC95-38D1-D96E-D542B819CDC0
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.sandbox.push.apple.com left intact
{"reason":"DeviceTokenNotForTopic"}%
```

[image: push cert]